# Python script works when called from cmd but not via Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I made a script to sort some files on a folder. It works just fine until it gets to the end where I try to write the path of some files into a .txt folder.

```
f = open("./output.txt", "w")   
f.write(output)
f.close()
```

That's literally it.

If I run the script via cmd it creates the file, adds the output and exits. If I run it via double clicking it, it sorts the folder and closes just before opening the file.

Also I don't know how to stop the prompt from closing instantly after failing so I don't know which error I get.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try it with a full path to an output file in a directory you know you have write access to instead of `./output.txt`?

Comment: Also, while somewhat hacky, you can force the window to say open by ending your program with `input("Press any key to close")`. Although you may need to use `try/except` to get that far.

Comment: @BlackVegetable that works but it doesn't show any error, it simply pauses after printing "opening .txt"(which I added ofc).

Comment: Just a guess, but I'll bet you are writing to a file that you DO have permissions for but it is relative to a different location than when you run this from `cmd`.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Do you mean like open("C:\Users\Ackman\Desktop\output.txt", "w") ?

Comment: @Ackman: yes, exactly. (BlackVegetable seems to suspect the same problem.)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz I'm already working with a folder on my desktop but I tried anyway. Nothing changed. Still works via cmd.

Comment: For the record, I tried using subprocess.call to echo into a text file, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: If you can have it display information, try having it print `os.path.abspath('./output.txt')` to see for sure where it's really trying to write

Comment: @EricRenouf I can't create the file, let alone write on it.

Comment: That's not what I asked for, and what makes you so sure you aren't creating a file?

Comment: I added constant messages after every action to see where it'd fail. The last line which was executed was the one trying to open the file, which failed. I'm sorry I misunderstood your suggestion, it actually helped me realize that it was trying to create the file in System32 (though that doesn't explain why specifying the exact, which I tried earlier, path didn't work). Thing is, I used `os.chdir(path)` to change my current directory and it works fine now. Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my current working directory was set to System32 when opening the file. After using `os.chdir(path)` to change the working directory I had no issues creating the file.

I'm not really sure why this happens, though, as I had no problems doing the same with a different script... And using the open function with a direct path to a file which I had permissions over didn't work either.

But hey, it's fixed.